# What is the difference between IRedisClientsManager and IRedisClientCacheManager in servicestack.redis

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

What is the difference between IRedisClientsManager and IRedisClientCacheManager in servicestack.redis.
I am trying to replace my appfabric distributed cache. Which client should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IRedisClientsManager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClientsManager.cs), which is the recommended default.